# I want to do a contest for the most loyal player of my track. Possible?

Tags: spotify

I would like to know how can I create an API that would keep track of who is my most loyal player on a certain track? I would make the API with a button on my site and clicking that would count plays. Is this possible?

Comment: As Glenn said, this is not possible with the API.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no way to do this with the API.

Comment: It's true. That being said, this is probably more of a comment than an answer.